# Do I get the regular download link to download Ubuntu in folder not an ISO file

Tags: downloads

How to get Ubuntu download in folder format not iso

Comment: The only Ubuntu I download is in ISO format (if I ignore package downloads).  You can `mount` an ISO and then access what is in the squashfs as if it's a directory filled with files, and I suspect that's what you need, but it's still downloaded as an ISO.

Comment: Why do you want "Ubuntu download in folder fomat?" What will you do with that? Ubuntu is not an application, It's an entire operating system. It needs to be booted